# useCallback necessary within React.memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider this example:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

type UserInputProps = {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
};

const UserInput = React.memo(({ onChange }: UserInputProps) => {
  // Is this `useCallback` redundant?
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />;
});

export default UserInput;
```

My questions are:

1. When the props consist of only `onChange` and no other elements, is the `useCallback` unnecessary in this case, since the entire component is already memo-ed based on `onChange`?
2. If we add an additional prop (say a `value` for the initial value for the `<input>`), then I think `useCallback` becomes useful, since otherwise `handleChange` will be recreated even if `onChange` doesn't change but `value` is changed. Is that correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When the props contains only `onChange` and no other elements, is the `useCallback` unnecessary in this case, since the entire component is already memo-ed based on `onChange`?

It's memoized based on all props, not just `onChange`. Yes, `useCallback` is unnecessary there.

> If we add an additional prop (say a `value` for the initial value for the `<input>`), then I think `useCallback` becomes useful, since otherwise `handleChange` will be recreated even if `onChange` doesn't change but value is changed. Is that correct?

If you want to update `value` and not update `onChange` when updating the `input`, you'd add `value` to your props and continue to use `useCallback` for your `handleChange` (if you like, so that React doesn't have to swap in a new event handler when it's setting the value; my impression is that's often overkill). E.g.:

```
const UserInput = React.memo(({ onChange, value }: UserInputProps) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
});
```

That will use the latest `value` and reuse the previous `handleChange` if the `onChange` prop hasn't changed.

You might not keep `React.memo` in that case, if you're expecting that `value` will get changed as a result of the `onChange`. That is, if you expect the common case to be that `value` *will* be different each time your component is called, then `React.memo`'s check of the props is extra work you might not keep:

```
const UserInput = ({ onChange, value }: UserInputProps) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

But you can keep it if you want `React.memo` to keep checking the props and not call your function when neither prop changes.

If you **just** want to supply the **initial** value to your component and then control it locally, you could continue to use `React.memo` (since it still renders the same thing for the same input props), in which case you don't need `useCallback`:

```
const UserInput = React.memo(({ onChange, initialValue }: UserInputProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    onChange(event.target.value);
  };

  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
});
```

That will only get called when `onChange` or `initialValue` changes. You could use also `useCallback` there in order to, again, only update the `onChange` on the `input` when the `onChange` prop changes, to avoid having React remove the old handler and set the new one when just the `value` changes:

```
const UserInput = React.memo(({ onChange, initialValue }: UserInputProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setValue(event.target.value);
      onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [onChange]
 );

  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
});
```

---

Side note: One thing to remember is that a new `handleChange` function is created every time your component function is called, even when you're using `useCallback`. It has to be, so it can be passed into `useCallback` as an argument. The only difference is whether you *use* that new function, or the original one that was created the first time (the result of `useCallback`). I think the reason for reusing the first one that was created for a given set of dependencies is to minimize changes passed to child components.

Comment: "you'd add `value` to your props, remove `React.memo`, and continue to use `useCallback` for your handleChange" -- why would I remove `React.memo` in this case? Wouldn't that cause `UserInput` to rerender even when no prop has changed?

Comment: @ZizhengTai - Good question. I've updated the answer to clarify that. You might remove it or not depending. If you think your component will be called a lot with the same `value` and `onChange`, you might keep it. But in that part of the answer I was assuming that `onChange` in the parent would update `value` nearly every time, which just makes `React.memo`'s check of the props extra work. It totally depends, though, so again, good question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> When the props consist of only `onChange` and no other elements, **is the `useCallback` unnecessary in this case**, since the entire component is already memo-ed based on onChange?

No, **it might be necessary**, `memo` and `useCallback` don't serve the same purpose.

Without `useCallback` you may have "heavy computation" on every render:

> "heavy computation" refers to a generic case and not to this specific example where you only pass the event's value.

```
const UserInput = React.memo(({ onChange = () => {} }) => {
  // Uncomment for memoization
  // Note that you can implement useCallback with useMemo

  // const handleChange = useMemo(() => {
  //   console.log("heavy computation memoized");
  //   return event => {
  //     onChange(event.target.value);
  //   };
  // }, [onChange]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    // Here we can have some heavy computation
    // Not related to this specific usecase
    console.log("heavy computation on every render");
    onChange(event.target.value);
  };

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />;
});
```

> If we add an additional prop (say a value for the initial value for the ), then I think `useCallback` becomes useful, since otherwise `handleChange` will be recreated even if onChange doesn't change but value is changed. Is that correct?

If you are going to use controlled component (due to use of `value` prop of `input`), **the `initialValue` will be initialized once**, so it pretty useless trying to memorize it (for what purpose?):

```
const UserInputWithValue = ({ onChange, initialValue }) => {
  // initilized once, no need to memoize
  const [value,setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setValue(event.target.value)
      onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  // Controlled
  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

[image: Edit objective-brown-nyuyc]

Comment: What '"heavy computation" are you talking about in the first part of your answer?

Comment: Its not related to this specific usecase where you only passing the event value, I tried to explain the generic case of "useCallback inside Memo"

Comment: I *think* I know what you're trying to say, it's just that the "Here we can have some heavy computation" comment above is in the change *handler*, not something creating the handler; it runs when the handler runs, not when it's built. Perhaps you're thinking of `useMemo`, where although you're creating a new function every time, you can avoid *running* that new function every time. (Not a factor for `useCallback`, because `useCallback(fn, [deps])` is just `useMemo(() => fn, [deps]);`, that "build me a handler" function has no computation to speak of.) (Anyway, still a good answer.)